# Audacity 3.0.2 doesn't save mp3 tags

Tags: audio-recording

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.4 LTS, and Audacity 3.0.2.

Each time I save some audio as MP3, I lose the tags.

I'm talking about Artist, Song title, Album title and Year text fields.

If I save the same audio as WAV, I get the tags.

What Am I doing wrong? Is it my fault, or it is a bug?

Some idea to fix this?

Comment: How did you installed Audacity? Please add output of `apt-cache policy audacity` ; `snap list | grep -i Audacity` ; `flatpak list | grep -i Audacity` to the question.

Comment: I don't know what to say. I just saved another audio file, and now all the MP3 tags are in the file!!! It is so weird. What could I did wrong? ???